# Why is my PHP PDO Insert attempt resulting in a SQLSTATE[23000]?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this PHP PDO insert query that I'm working with, and I'm getting this error that my `r_title` is Null, but when I run a `var_dump($r_title, $_POST['r_title'])` on it, it does NOT return Null. The whole error looks like the following -

**string(9) "My Review" string(9) "My Review" SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'r_title' cannot be null**

How can this field be both Null and NOT null at the same time?

Here is my code and various attempts -

**input query**

```
    $sql = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `reviews`(`r_date`, `r_title`, `v_name`, `v_email`, `host`, `host_type`, `r_features`, `r_security`, `r_service`, `r_reliability`, `r_overall`, `thumbs`, `comments`) 
                                         VALUES (:r_date, :r_title, :v_name, :v_email, :host, :host_type, :r_features, :r_security, :r_service, :r_reliablility, :r_overall, :thumbs, :comments)');
```

**Get data from form**

```
$timestamp = time(); //F, j, Y -> Full Month, day of mo w/o leading zeros, full 4-digit year
$r_date = date("F/jS/Y",$timestamp);
$r_title = $_POST['r_title'];
$v_name = $_POST['v_name'];
$v_email = $_POST['v_email'];
$host = $_POST['host'];
$host_type = $_POST['host_type'];
$r_features = $_POST['r_features'];
$r_security = $_POST['r_security'];
$r_service = $_POST['r_service'];
$r_reliability = $_POST['r_reliability'];

$r_overall = ($r_features + $r_security + $r_service + $r_reliability) / 4;

$thumbs = $_POST['thumbs'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
```

**Bind Params and Execute**

```
$sql->bindValue(':r_date', $r_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':r_title', $r_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':v_name', $v_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':v_email', $v_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':host', $host, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':host_type', $host_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':r_features', $r_features, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_security', $r_security, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_service', $r_service, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_reliability', $r_reliability, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_overall', $r_overall, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':thumbs', $thumbs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':comments', $comments, PDO::PARAM_STR);
var_dump($r_title, $_POST['r_title']);
$sql->execute();
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you try removing the `_` from the parameters that have them, instead naming them `:rdate`, `:rtitle` etc? It's possible that PDO isn't liking the non-alphanumeric character.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Well, I didn't have the underscore in the code that I used last year, so I guess that could be possible. Lemmie try and get back to you.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I took the underscores out of the parameters, but it still didn't work. Also, I went back and double-checked my code from last year, and there WERE parameters in there with Underscores, so that wasn't it.

Comment: Please check your codes and see `:r_reliablility` vs `:r_reliability`

Comment: It seams that this error also can occur, when a column name is mistyped. Have you checked all names (case sensitive)?

Comment: See my edit in the OP. I'm now getting a new error

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for pointing that out. I find it ironic I cannot reliably spell reliability.

Comment: Your `r_title` column is declared to be `NOT NULL`, but your variable bound to that contains a `null` value.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone - I made all my table names lowercase for that reason, but I just double-checked and everything is lowercase.

Comment: `var_dump($r_title, $_POST['r_title']);`

Comment: @u_mulder - I did that, and got the following result - string(19) "My Review!" string(19) "My Review!" It doesn't look like it's empty . . .

Comment: Check `r_title` column type, maybe it's not `char/varchar` and you're trying to add `string` there. Check `$r_title` once again right before query executing.

Comment: @u_mulder - `r_title` column is varchar. Also, even though the `var_dump` shows it isn't empty, when I try to `execute()` again, it still says it is `NULL`. I took the  2 `:rtitle` and the 2 `$r_title` and copied them to each other so there are no typos there, and still not working.

Comment: I advise you to delete this question as it's already started with a syntax error and create a new one with proper code and problem description.

Comment: @u_mulder - Alright, I'll do that. Thank you.

Comment: @u_mulder - Actually, it appears thanks to excessive down-votes I've lost the right/ability to ask questions . . . Now what?

Comment: Never heard of such option o_O

Comment: @u_mulder - Since I'm not allowed to ask any more questions, I just re-worked this question so it only reflects the current situation. Might not be ideal, as now the comments don't make much sense, but I'm not sure what else I could have done here.

Comment: Try use `$sql->debugDumpParams();`, get the values you bind, replace in your SQL, run/check it and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was.

> **Order Matters! Define your variables BEFORE you try to bind them!**

While I was posting my question up there, I noticed that I was offering my sample code in a different order than it was in my code editor. I did that to try and make it easier to understand for those reading.

In my original code, the section where I get data from the $_POST[] was AFTER the section where I bound my values.

The reason no one could help me is because they literally couldn't **SEE** the problem.

> **Be sure to post your code AS IT APPEARS in your editor**, to ensure if
>   there is an error with the order, others can spot it and point it out
>   to you.

Once I moved my $_POST[] info ABOVE the section where I bound my values, the whole thing worked fine!

Meaning, instead of the following, as in my example:

```
//get data from $_POST
$timestamp = time(); //F, j, Y -> Full Month, day of mo w/o leading zeros, full 4-digit year
$r_date = date("F/jS/Y",$timestamp);
$r_title = $_POST['r_title'];
$v_name = $_POST['v_name'];
$v_email = $_POST['v_email'];
$host = $_POST['host'];
$host_type = $_POST['host_type'];
$r_features = $_POST['r_features'];
$r_security = $_POST['r_security'];
$r_service = $_POST['r_service'];
$r_reliability = $_POST['r_reliability'];
$r_overall = ($r_features + $r_security + $r_service + $r_reliability) / 4;
$thumbs = $_POST['thumbs'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];


//Bind Params and Execute

$sql->bindValue(':r_date', $r_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':r_title', $r_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':v_name', $v_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':v_email', $v_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':host', $host, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':host_type', $host_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':r_features', $r_features, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_security', $r_security, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_service', $r_service, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_reliability', $r_reliability, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':r_overall', $r_overall, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':thumbs', $thumbs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':comments', $comments, PDO::PARAM_STR);
var_dump($r_title, $_POST['r_title']);
$sql->execute();
```

I actually had THIS on my page:

```
    //Bind Params

    $sql->bindValue(':r_date', $r_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':r_title', $r_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':v_name', $v_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':v_email', $v_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':host', $host, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':host_type', $host_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':r_features', $r_features, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':r_security', $r_security, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':r_service', $r_service, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':r_reliability', $r_reliability, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':r_overall', $r_overall, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindValue(':thumbs', $thumbs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql->bindValue(':comments', $comments, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//get data from $_POST and execute
    $timestamp = time(); //F, j, Y -> Full Month, day of mo w/o leading zeros, full 4-digit year
    $r_date = date("F/jS/Y",$timestamp);
    $r_title = $_POST['r_title'];
    $v_name = $_POST['v_name'];
    $v_email = $_POST['v_email'];
    $host = $_POST['host'];
    $host_type = $_POST['host_type'];
    $r_features = $_POST['r_features'];
    $r_security = $_POST['r_security'];
    $r_service = $_POST['r_service'];
    $r_reliability = $_POST['r_reliability'];
    $r_overall = ($r_features + $r_security + $r_service + $r_reliability) / 4;
    $thumbs = $_POST['thumbs'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    var_dump($r_title, $_POST['r_title']);
    $sql->execute();
```

Comment: gg, wp, no re... Although it's worth noting that you can just `$sql->bindValue(':r_title', $_POST['r_title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);`, no need for all those intermediary variables.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Valid point. This code is based off of code I found last year while learning how to do this. So I simply followed the code. But what you say does make sense.